# Can't consume Mono.error when subscribed with fromCallable/fromSupplier

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to wrap method with fromCallable to execute my method from another thread. But when i return as `Mono.error`, my error consumer not catch any error when i subscribe to it. Instead it only prints Mono.error on my log. Am i doing it wrong?

```
Mono.fromCallable(()
                -> Mono.error(new Exception("error coming")))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .doOnError(throwable -> LOG.debug("error {}",throwable.getMessage()))
                .log()
                .subscribe(res ->LOG.debug("result {}", res),
                        err -> LOG.error("Error message {}", err.getMessage()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Callable` passed to `Mono.fromCallable(...)` should either:

1. return the element to emit, or
2. throw an exception (using the `throw` keyword).

In other words, the `Callable` should *not* return a `Mono` or `Flux`, which is what your example is doing.

Comment: i thought i can handle it same as the others Mono API like flatMap, etc.. thank you for your answer :)